# Typing the date time in textbox, does not change the selected value of date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I've used use [babakhani Persian datepicker](https://github.com/babakhani/pwt.datepicker) in my project.
There is a problem here. the selected value of date picker does not change on textbox value change!! How can I fix it in my project, myself?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/babareza/DqppC/)

I used

```
$("#example1").change(
    function (e) {
        $("#example1").pDatepicker();
    };
});
```

but the error is:

> too much recursion

since it calls change() recursively. (also .blur() is tested)

Comment: Your fiddle is working fine chrome and firefox. In which browser you are testing ?

Comment: It has not error. The problem is that the selected value of the date picker does not change by text box value change (typing the date time does not change the selected value of date picker)

Answer (score 0):

No need to use change event. you can directly use

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example1").pDatepicker();
});`

Also there is an additional `}` in your code.